# Send sort parameters from view with Pjax in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, yii2, pjax

This is the code of my view file. I use pjax to show some data with sorting feature. I am not using `grid view`. Everything is working good with pagination. All i need to send some sort parameters like sort by date etc. Don't understand how to send those parameters to controller and also need to send `per-page` parameter from view.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id'=>'saved-seller']); 
  //............div contents...........
echo \yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
                                        'pagination' => $pages,
                                    ]); ?>

<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try https://github.com/nterms/yii2-pagesize-widget

Comment: I am not using any grid view

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, I just looked in documentation of yii2 and pjax on github.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin([
   'id'=>'saved-seller',
   'clientOptions' => ['url' => YoururlToControllerWithParameters]
]);
```